# Horizontal Scrolling - white gap issue

Tags: html, css

I'm currently coding a horizontal site and the only issue I'm having is a white gap in between the divs. I've tried adding 0 padding and margin to all divs and it's still not working. Any one know what the issue is?

Here's a simple example of my issue:

https://codepen.io/Omgyouwould/pen/RZeegP

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.main_wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
}

/* colors */

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_wrap">
  <div class="wrapper green">
    <h1>Hello there.</h1>
    </br>
    <p>Use the botton scroll bar to navigate.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper blue">
    <h1>Hello there.</h1>
    </br>
    <p>Use the botton scroll bar to navigate.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper red">
    <h1>Hello there.</h1>
    </br>
    <p>Use the botton scroll bar to navigate.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a common issue with inline-block, some alternatives/workarounds are outlined [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). Adding a negative margin worked well enough, but this doesn't work on some older browsers (IE 6/7).

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I overlooked the -45px margin option.